# How to copy front part of string up to a delimiter

Tags: c

I need to grab the first part of a string up to and including the last backslash in a path.  I am fairly new to C. So I was wondering if the following code is a good approach?  Or is there a better way?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

   char szPath[260] = {0};
   strcpy(szPath, argv[0]);
   char* p = szPath;

   size_t len = strlen(argv[0]);
   p+=len;  //go to end of string

   int backpos = 0;
   while(*--p != '\\')
       ++backpos;

   szPath[len-backpos] = 0;

   printf("%s\n", szPath);

   return 0;
}
```

After receiving comments changed to this:

```
char szPath[260];
strcpy(szPath, argv[0]);

/*Scan a string for the last occurrence of a character.*/
char *p = strrchr(szPath, '\\');  

if (p) {
    *(p + 1) = 0;  /* retain backslash and null terminate after that */
} else {
    /* handle error */
}

printf("%s\n", szPath);
```

Comment: You don't handle the case where there is no `'\\'`

Comment: You also could just say `*p = 0;` rather than `szPath[len-backpos] = 0;` and drop the `backpos` altogether.

Comment: You've got an unchecked buffer overflow problem if `argv[0]` (which is, remember, the program (path) name) is longer than 260 bytes.

Comment: char szPath[260];
    strcpy(szPath, argv[0]);

    //Scan a string for the last occurrence of a character.
    char *p = strrchr(szPath, '\\');  

    if (p) {
        *(p + 1) = 0;  /* retain backslah and null terminate after that */
    } else {
        /* handle error */
    }

    printf("%s\n", szPath);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would go with `strrchr`. This assumes `str` points to writable memory:

```
char *p;
if ((p = strrchr(str, '\\'))
    *(p + 1) = 0; /* Since we passed it to strrchr, it's 0-terminated. */
```

Obviously, `basename` and `dirname` might be there if you are working with paths and might be more appropriate.